# Keras with tensorflow throws ResourceExhaustedError

Tags: tensorflow, out-of-memory, keras

For research purposes, I am training a neural network that is updating its weights differently depending on the parity of the epoch:

1) If the epoch is even, change the weights of the NN with backpropagation

2) If the epoch is odd, only update the model with `update_weights_with_custom_function()` therefore freeze the network.

Here is a simplified part of the code that implements this (notice the `epochs=1`):

```py
for epoch in range(nb_epoch):

    if epoch % 2 == 0:
        model.trainable = True    # Unfreeze the model
    else:
        model.trainable = False   # Freeze the model
    model.compile(optimizer=optim, loss=gaussian_loss, metrics=['accuracy'])

    hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
             batch_size=batch_size,
             epochs=1,
             shuffle=True,
             verbose=1,
             callbacks=[tbCallBack, csv_epochs, early_stop],
             validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))

    if epoch % 2 == 1:
        update_weights_with_custom_function()
```

**Problem:** after a few epoch, keras throws a `ResourceExhaustedError` but only with tensorflow, *not with theano*. It seems that looping over `compile()` is creating models without releasing them.

Therefore, what should I do? I know that `K.clear_session()` releases memory but it requires to save the model and reload it ([see](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5345)) which gives me some issues as `load_model()` in my case does not work out of the box.

I'm also open to other ways to do what I am trying to achieve (i.e. freezing a NN model depending on the parity of the epoch).

**Summary:** keras with tensorflow backend is throwing a `ResourceExhaustedError` because I am looping over `compile()`.

Comment: A similar situation has been reported here https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2973. However, it does not help me on how to remediate practically to the issue.

Comment: Why are you calling fit when you set your model to be `nontrainable`? Shouldn't evaluate be enough in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marcin Możejko pointed out, using `eval()` is doing exactly what I was trying to achieve.

I added a custom callback (inspiration was [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2548)), which avoids the loop over `compile()`

The problem is now solved, even if the tensorflow issue was not addressed directly.